# How to use normal Filter together with SearchFilter on Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, filter, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF(Django Rest Framework).

I declared a ModelViewSet, and now I want to add filters on that.

```
class GoodsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    class Filter(FilterSet):    
        class Meta:
            model = m.Goods

    filter_class = Filter
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, Filter)
    search_fields = ['name',]
    queryset = m.Goods.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.GoodsSerializer
```

Seeing that I declared a Filter sub class and applied it with:

```
filter_class = Filter
```

It worked at the beginning, before I add the lines:

```
filter_backends = (SearchFilter, Filter)
search_fields = ['name',]
```

Which was told by [the doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter).

And now the search filter is applied while the normal `filter_class` is skipped.

One word, they cannot work together.

How to work around this?

Comment: rename your filter_class to some other class name ? ex. filter_class = My_Custom_Filter

Comment: @soupboy thank you, not that issue. I've worked out a solution and posted as an answer. I just want to post the answer here.

Comment: @AlfredHuang Do you have blog on this issue? I want to see full implementation. It is still hard for me to figure out. Your solution is interesting.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally, I found we should specify two `filter_backends` together:

```
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class GoodsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    class Filter(FilterSet):    
        class Meta:
            model = m.Goods

    filter_class = Filter
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    search_fields = ['name',]
    queryset = m.Goods.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.GoodsSerializer
```

Or we can ignore the `filter_backends` field on a specific `ViewSet` class, but apply them globally in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ... other configurations
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}
```

So that the `filter_class` and `search_fields` options are available on the ViewSet at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me:

```
    from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
    from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
    from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter, OrderingFilter
```

--------views.py-----------------------------

```
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter ,OrderingFilter)
    filter_fields =('completed',)
    ordering =('-date_created',)
    search_fields =('task_name',)
```