# Search filter django drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i want to get image as multiple search keyword at once:

views.py:

```
class ImageSearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
      authentication_classes = []
      permission_classes = []
      queryset = Image.objects.all()
      serializer_class = ImageSearchSerializer
      filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
      search_fields = ['image_keyword']
```

models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
      license_type = (
         ('Royalty-Free','Royalty-Free'),
         ('Rights-Managed','Rights-Managed')
       )
      image_number = models.CharField(default=random_image_number,max_length=12,unique=True)
      title = models.CharField(default=random_image_number,max_length = 100)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'image' , default = 'demo/demo.png')
      thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbs', blank=True, null=True)
      category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      shoot = models.ForeignKey(ImageShoot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Image', null=True,blank=True)
      image_keyword = models.TextField(max_length=1000)


      def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

urls.py:

```
    path('image_search/',views.ImageSearchView.as_view(), name = 'image_search'),
```

when i make a request from postman:

```
localhost:8000/api/image_search?search=boxing cricket kohli marykom
```

if i put & between them then it doesn't work also:

[image]
i want to get every image which has keyword like any of the search parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use normal Filter together with SearchFilter on Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417970/how-to-use-normal-filter-together-with-searchfilter-on-django-rest-framework)

Comment: no i don't want this i need just or condition between search keywords

Comment: did you tried to separate keywords with `&` like this: `localhost:8000/api/image_search?search=boxing&cricket&kohli&marykom` ?

Comment: yes it doesn't work see the image

Comment: try this: `localhost:8000/api/image_search?search=boxing,cricket,kohli,marykom`

Comment: it doesn't work its simply search for boxing,cricket,kohli

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use `django-filter` for this case, you can read more here:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html

If you don't want install anything - you can override `get_queryset` method of your `ListAPIView`. You need to get all the query-params you need and return the queryset filtered by them. In this case your code will be like this:

```
def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    keywords = self.request.query_params.get('search')
    if keywords:
        queryset = queryset.filter(image_keyword__in=keywords.split(','))
    return queryset
```

In this case make sure to remove `filter_backends`, `search_fields` and `queryset`  fields from `ImageSearchView` class

Comment: @afk there was a typo in `image_keyword` `filter` argument name. Try fixed version of snippet

Comment: i think its the same code if i search like this localhost:8000/api/image_search?search=boxer mary kom its showing the image with exact image keyword if just search boxer then its not returning any thing

Comment: also if i add another keyword of different image with , its not showing anything

Answer (score 1):

> The django-rest-framework-filters package works together with the DjangoFilterBackend class, and allows you to easily create filters across relationships, or create multiple filter lookup types for a given field.

read [there](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#django-rest-framework-filters)

[that](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#configuring-complexfilterbackend) part of docs for you i think

```
title__startswith=Who, title__startswith=What
title__startswith%3DWho, title__startswith%3DWhat
(title__startswith%3DWho) | (title__startswith%3DWhat)
%28title__startswith%253DWho%29%20%7C%20%28title__startswith%253DWhat%29
filters=%28title__startswith%253DWho%29%20%7C%20%28title__startswith%253DWhat%29
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the search param multiple times like this? In this case, it should 'search' query param should end up as a list.

```
localhost:8000/api/image_search?search=&search=boxing&search=cricket&search=kohli&search=marykom
```

Comment: yeah i have tried that it search the one parameter only